# Joomla contact form

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails, smtp

I'm using Joomla 3.0 and I created a basic contact form. I created a `mail id` in *info@domain.com* in Webmail.

In the contact form, after filling the details and submitting the form, I'm getting the error:

> smtp connect failed.

The mail setting details are below:

- send mail: **yes**
- mailer: **smtp**
- from email: **info@domain.com**
- from name: **name**
- smtp authentification: **no**
- smtp security: **ssl**
- smtp port: **465**
- smtp username: **info@domain.com**
- smtp password: `****`
- smtp host: **relay-hosting.secureserver.net**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You have the mail connection settings wrong. You need to get the correct settings from your webhost.

Comment: Nothing else is wrong??

Comment: For one, smtp authentication should be set to YES, otherwise it can't actually authenticate on your server.

Comment: i set all the details like smtp authentication to yes, but still its not workin

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using SMTP instead of PHP Mail?

Comment: no the problem is fixed i downloaded one joomla component, and i set smtp to phpmail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hosts blacklist SMTP mail servers and the PHP mail setting just never consistently works. We ended up having to use mandrill's API http://mandrill.com/.

There is an exellent extension to use the API instead for all mail on your site. CMandrill.
https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/mandrill-transactional-emails-made-easy

This of course cannot use your current SMTP host but it is free up to 12000 emails a month (so you probably will never need to pay).

Other then that you can only really play with the settings and test until it works, but in our experience it could work once but not the next time, the general SMTP protocol has issues in shared environments (if that is what you are on).

Currently Joomla does not actually have anything to debug email issues, the phpmailer library it uses in JMail does have the ability, but the last time I looked at the class it was not implemented to log the data anywhere.